# Is it possible to create a publicly viewable dashboard?

Tags: reporting, permissions, dashboard

I understand how to make a dashboard "public". But public seems to mean visible to other members of the Salesforce organization?

I would like to make a report viewable by anyone without logging into Salesforce. Does that mean I need to cram everything into a Visualforce page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites is the only option for you, in case you want users to access content without having to LogIn.

You have to grant read permissions to guest user for accessing the object/fields involved in the reports.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes. You would need to expose your data by way of a configured Site. When you do this, you'll want to take extra care not to expose sensitive information, so make sure the code is properly taking security in consideration as it's being written and configured.

Comment: You're basically saying to recreate the report on a Visualforce page and make that page a Site? I've come to this conclusion after a lot of Googling. But would say "Essentially, no". You can't easily expose a dashboard. Instead, you can (with great pain) recreate the content display on a Salesforce Site. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry. The first sentence was in regards to the first question. I'll clear this up when I get on a computer. There's no convenient way to show dashboards publicly that I'm aware of.